# Postgres not listing operators and functions

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using the `\do` and `\df` command to list operators and functions. But it returns an empty table. What am I doing wrong?

```bash
bpsimple=> \do
                             List of operators
 Schema | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type | Description 
--------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------
(0 rows)

bpsimple=> 
bpsimple=> \df
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)

bpsimple=> 
bpsimple=>
```

Comment: 1) Have you created user functions and or operators? If not you will need to do `\doS` and `\dfS` to get the system ones. 2) If you created user functions and operators then it is probably a `search_path` issue. To verify do `\du *.*` and `\do *.*`. If that is the case `SET search_path = <schema list>` per [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

Comment: Well have you defined any that you would expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see system functions and operators, use `\dfS` and `\doS`.